# What does a domain being maximal mean?

Tags: complex-analysis

The following question was given for our complex analysis homework

Find a branch $L$ of the logarithm function such that $f(z)=L(2z+2i-3)$ is analytic at $-i$ and $f(-i)=log3+3\pi i $ Is the domain of $L$ maximal? For this branch L determine the largest domain $D$ in which $f$ is analytic.

I could find a branch satisfying the conditions, and ind the largest domain such that f is analytic, but what does is the domain maximal mean?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: If there is no analytic extension of the function to a larger domain than the given one, the given domain is maximal (for that function).

Comment: Thank you! I took $L(z)=log|z|+i\theta(z) $ where $ \theta(z) \in argZ $ and $2\pi$<$ \theta (z)$< $4\pi$ and the domain as $\Bbb C$\[0,$\infty$) so the domain is maximal for it isn't it?

Comment: Yes, since any attempt to expand the domain takes you across the branch cut, where the function jumps to a different value. (This is possible to avoid, but then you have to leave the complex plane behind and work with Riemann surfaces. But that is a topic for a more advanced course, perhaps.)